# linQ max return null vall

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I Have a model like this

```
public partial class TableNames
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] 
    public int IntId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in a controller I'm Trying to get max IntIdfrom that model

```
var max = from c in db.TableNames
          select c;

int? Max = max.AsQueryable().Max(x => x.IntId); //This isntruction throws an error
int IntId = ( Max == null ? 1 : Max + 1);
```

When the table has no records (it's empty) , the controller throws this error

```
The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. 
Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

How can I do to fix it ?

Comment: maybe `max.Where(x=>x.HasValue).Max(x => x.IntId)` ?

Comment: I guess "AsQueryable()" is not required. Try remove it.

Comment: The answer to this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165605/whats-the-neatest-way-to-achieve-minordefault-in-linq

Comment: Nothing, I'm trying your suggestion, but x doesn´t show me HasValue. And the answer you suggestme is asking me for IQueryable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
int? Max = max.AsQueryable().Max(x => (int?)x.IntId);
```

Comment: Excellent .. Tks. for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not wish to deal with Nullable and want a default value (based upon Splendor's code), you may do something similar to the following:

`int Max = max.AsQueryable().Max(x => (int?)x.IntId) ?? 1;`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
max.Where(i => i.IntId.HasValue).Select(i => i.IntId.Value).Max()
```