Sequence contains no elements in LINQ
In the code shown here, I am getting an error in LINQ:

Sequence contains no elements

When the reason column contains data, it is throwing this exception. Please suggest how to handle this exception.
Code:
if (StudentDetails.rows
                  .Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.reason) && !c.leave) 
                  .Min(c => c.joiningdate) < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-180))
    return true;


The implication is that there are no rows where "reason" is null and "leaveL is false.  Do you think there are?

@TimRoberts, When reason contains data and leave is false it throws error

Firstly, that's not an answer to the question you were asked. If you mean that you do think there are then the answer to the question is "yes" and that's what you should have said. If you actually mean something else, be clear what that is.

It is almost certainly the case that there is no data that matches those criteria and you just think there is. The way to actually find out is to test that, which you should already have done. Use a conventional loop over all the data and put an if block inside that tests those same criteria. You can then put a breakpoint inside that block and see whether it gets hit. If it doesn't then there is no matching data and that's why you get an error message telling you that. If it does get hit then your system is broken because that LINQ should work in that case.

Your Where clause selects all rows where "reason" is empty and "leave" is false.  If "reason" always has data, then OF COURSE the resulting sequence will have no elements.


In the code shown here, I am getting an error in LINQ:
Sequence contains no elements

Based on your shared code snippet and description I have tried to reproduce your issue and I was able to simulate the error you are getting. Following is the reference for you.



When the reason column contains data, it is throwing this exception.
Please suggest how to handle this exception.

According to the error message which indicates can happen if all elements in StudentDetails.rows either have a non-null reason or leave is true, resulting in an empty sequence for the Min method to operate on.
So the way you are trying would always encounter this exception if the condition doesn't meet.
In order to overcome the exception, you should first check if there are any elements in the filtered sequence before calling Min. You can use the Any method in Linq to ensure that the sequence is not empty.
Let's say, I have following data set:
private readonly List<Student> _studentDetails = new List<Student>
{
    new Student { reason = "Medical", leave = true, joiningdate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 10) },
    new Student { reason = "Personal", leave = true, joiningdate = new DateTime(2022, 2, 15) },
    new Student { reason = "Vacation", leave = true, joiningdate = new DateTime(2021, 3, 20) },
    new Student { reason = "Disciplinary", leave = false, joiningdate = new DateTime(2023, 4, 1) },
    new Student { reason = "Health", leave = true, joiningdate = new DateTime(2021, 5, 30) },
};

As you can noticed above dataset would faild the condition, in that scenario I would modify the query as following:
var filteredRows = _studentDetails
    .Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.reason) && !c.leave);

if (filteredRows.Any() && filteredRows.Min(c => c.joiningdate) < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-180))
{
    return Ok(true);
}

So in filteredRows is first assigned the result of the Where method, filtering the rows based on your conditions. The Any method is then used to check if filteredRows contains any elements. Only if filteredRows is not empty, the Min method is called to find the minimum joiningdate and no exception would thrown anymore.
Output:


Note: Please refer to this official document, if you need additional details.

The error is from Min function. It throws exception when the source contains no elements. Following is the summary of Min function,
//
// Summary:
//     Returns the minimum value in a sequence of System.Int32 values.
//
// Parameters:
//   source:
//     A sequence of System.Int32 values to determine the minimum value of.
//
// Returns:
//     The minimum value in the sequence.
//
// Exceptions:
//   T:System.ArgumentNullException:
//     source is null.
//
//   T:System.InvalidOperationException:
//     source contains no elements.
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static int Min(this IEnumerable<int> source)

When there is data in all the rows of reason column, your Where function will return empty enumerable. This is because IsNullOrEmpty is your first condition. And since you are using && operation, the statement will always evaluate to false when the reason column is not null or empty.
You can solve this by using DefaultIfEmpty as explained by Christoffer Lette in this Stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2167461/24889207. For reference types in C#, the default value is null. So, you may need to handle that.
On a side note, you can directly return the result of Min instead of wrapping it in if condition and returning true.
Example:
return StudentDetails.rows
    .Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.reason) && !c.leave)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Min(c => c?.joiningdate ?? DateTime.UtcNow) < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-180)


Min throws an exception if there are no elements, but only if T is a non-nullable valuetype. So you can just cast to nullable.
if (StudentDetails.rows
    .Where(c => !c.leave && string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.reason)) 
    .Min(c => (DateTime?) c.joiningdate) < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-180))
    return true;

